# Evaluate extreme point based on eigenvalue & eigenvector of Hess Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hessian-matrix

Is there a case, in which at an extreme point there are more than 1 positive EValue? This would lead to more than 1 EVector that shows the steepest increase of a function. Up till now I haven't run into a case like described, but I wonder about the possibility of having one. I think it is not possible because there is only one direction to make the function change fastest.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient will tell you in which direction a function increases the fastest. Eigenvalues being positive at a point means the function is strictly convex at that point. These are different things.

Coming to the specific question (is there a case in which at an extreme point there are more than 1 positive eigenvalue) the answer is yes:

Consider, for instance

\begin{align}
f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 &\to \mathbb{R} \nonumber \\
(x,y) &\mapsto 2x^2+y^2 \nonumber
\end{align}

The Hessian matrix at extreme point $(0,0)$ has two positive eigenvalues, 2 and 4.

Comment: Thanks. But fastest I would say

Comment: You are right...

Comment: @pendermath thanks for the comment but that it doesnt really answer my question ...

Comment: I have edited my answer to specifically answer your question. Better?

Comment: @pendermath Yes absolutely! the 2  eigenvectors show the steepest increase in x and y direction respectively and the 2 eigenvalues show it changes by how much.